# What is the "prototype" linkage for Objects created via the Object Literal Notation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My first post on Stack Overflow and so a complete newbie here and I am still getting used to the rules / annotations followed on this forum and so please do excuse this aspiring "developer" ;-)

While reading through Crockford's "*Good Parts*", I came across a line that said:

> ### Every object is linked to a prototype object from which it can inherit properties. All objects created from object literals are linked to Object.prototype, an object that comes standard with JavaScript.

So to test this out I wrote the following JScript code:

```
var Student = {}
console.log(Student.isPrototypeOf(Object.prototype))
```

Note:

1. I am executing this via the **Browser Console** and hence the function - `console.log(...)`.
2. I am guessing the way the Student variable declared here is using the "*Object Literal Notation*". Isn't that correct ?

So the second line -

```
console.log(Student.isPrototypeOf(Object.prototype))
```

returned a **false** instead of a **true**. Shouldn't that display a **true** instead of a <strike>false</strike> ?

Well doesn't that contradict the lines from the Book that I mentioned above ?

So here is the snippet in action -

```js
var Student = {};
alert(Student.isPrototypeOf(Object.prototype));
```

*I am sure that I missing something here for sure!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype of `Student` (and all other objects created via an [object initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)) is `Object.prototype`.

> I am guessing the way the `Student` variable declared here is using the "Object Literal Notation". Isn't that correct ?

Yes, that's one word for it. The spec calls it an object initialiser.*

> So the second line -
>
> `console.log(Student.isPrototypeOf(Object.prototype))`
>
> returned a false instead of a true. Shouldn't that display a true instead of a false ?

No, because `Student` isn't the prototype of `Object.prototype`; it's the other way around:

```js
var student = {};
snippet.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(student)); // true
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is to only use mixed case with an initial capital letter for *constructor functions* and sometimes for objects used as pseudo-namespaces. Simple objects, and simple functions, start with a lower case letter by convention (so, `student` rather than `Student`).

---

* "initialiser" with an "s", not a "z", for some reason. Eich is an American, but either whoever wrote the spec was British or, as ECMA was originally a primarily European organization — until 1994 it was the **European** Computer Manufacturers Association, after all — perhaps their editor just insisted on British rather than American English spelling.

Comment: Thank You T.J. Well that makes sense and I think I got it wrong. Some times you need that "other" pair of eyes to help you grasp the essence of it. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the relation backwards.

```
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Student) // true

Student instanceOf Object // true
```